# Ports in AWS appear closed

Tags: amazon-web-services

I try to open all ports in ECL2 (Windows Server 2012 R2), but in my VPS ports appear closed.

Rules panel:

[image: Rules panel]

Ports VPS:

[image: Ports VPS]

Comment: What is ECL2? Have you looked at the Windows Firewall to check you've opened that up? Your security group is far too permissive.

Answer (score 0):

The ports may be open correctly within the EC2 Security Groups. Some of the ports in your screenshot don't have services that could even be enabled in Windows Server. And others need to be explicitly installed.

To confirm whether your problem is because of services that aren't even running, check your service network bindings by running the following at a command prompt and looking for services listening on those ports:

```
netstat -an
```